# How to draw SVG path points in Java using Path2D (or any Shape drawer)?

Tags: javascript, java, html, svg, path-2d

I've been looking for a way to take the points from a `SVG` and apply that in a `Path2D` painter.

The parsing task is not my point here, the problem is understand how the points works in a canvas and how to apply it to a `Path2D`.

For example, consider I have this `SVG` tag:

```html
<svg>
    <path d = "
    m 51.688 5.25
    c 10 20 30 40 50 60
    z">
    </path>
</svg>
```

This just moves the drawer to the first point, draws a curve using these points and closes the path.

I tried to apply this to a `Path2D` like this:

```
float x = 200, y = 200;
Path2D.Float painter = new Path2D.Float();

painter.moveTo(51.688+x, 5.25+y);
painter.curveTo(10+x, 20+y, 30+x, 40+y, 50+x, 60+y);
painter.closePath();
```

As the points from `SVG` are relatives I summed x and y fields to points, but I got this result:
[image]

This was just a little test to check if the drawing works and I need use this with more complex paths, and as I need to draw up to 50 SVG paths `Batik` was not a good approach, considering it was so slow to render only one svg image of my project.

Then what I need to know is if is possible to draw the SVG path using its points directly like this. If yes, how to fix my ideia? If not, how a good way to draw the path? P.s.: i'm targeting `swing`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to understand how SVG path commands work, the best source is to read the [SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html#paths-PathData).  It is all explained clearly there. I'm not sure why you came here to ask first.

Lower case path commands (like `c`) are **relative**. Their coordinates should be considered offsets from the end point of the last path segment.

So the equivalent to your path description should be:

```
painter.moveTo(51.688, 5.25);
painter.curveTo(51.688 + 10, 5.25 + 20, 51.688 + 30, 5.25 + 40, 51.688 + 50, 5.25 + 60);
painter.closePath();
```

(I've left out your `x` and `y` parameters here for the sake of clarity).